# Passing initial value in formset

Tags: python, django, time-and-attendance

#### Models

```py
attendance_choices = (
    ('absent', 'Absent'),
    ('present', 'Present')
)

class Head_of_department(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name 

class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    head_of_department = models.ForeignKey('Head_of_department', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

class Attendance(models.Model):
    head_of_department = models.ForeignKey('Head_of_department', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    attendance = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=attendance_choices, blank=True)
```

#### Views

```py
class Attendancecreate(CreateView):
    model = Attendance
    fields = ['employee']
    success_url = '/dashboard/'

    def get_context_data(self,** kwargs):
        context = super(Attendancecreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = AttendanceFormset(queryset=Attendance.objects.none(), instance=Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email), initial=[{'employee': employee} for employee inself.get_initial()['employee']])
        context['attendance_form'] = Attendanceform()
        email = self.request.user.email
        hod = Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email)
        context["employees"] = Employee.objects.filter(head_of_department =hod)
        return context

    def get_initial(self):
        email = self.request.user.email
        hod = Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email)
        initial = super(Attendancecreate , self).get_initial()
        initial['employee'] = Employee.objects.filter(head_of_department=hod)
        return initial

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = AttendanceFormset(queryset=Attendance.objects.none(), instance=Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email), initial=[{'employee': employee} for employee inself.get_initial()['employee']))
        if formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(formset)

     def form_valid(self, formset):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.head_of_department = get_object_or_404(Head_of_department, email=self.request.user.email)
            instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
     def form_invalid(self, formset):
        print ('errors')
        print (formset.errors)
```

#### Forms

```py
class Attendanceform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ('employee','attendance','hod')

AttendanceFormset = inlineformset_factory(Head_of_department,Attendance,fields=('attendance',))
```

#### Template

```html
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
{{ form }}
<br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

#### Error

Below shown square brackets was printed in the console when I used print(formset.errors)

```
[]
```

How to pass employees as initial values for attendance model as shown below in the images, employees will be rendered and rendered values have to be passed as employee in attendance model.

Is there any workaround with modelformset or inlineformset ? I can't get it right with the views I have included in the question .

[image]

Comment: show us AttendanceFormset definition

Comment: i have edited the code , please do look

Comment: I already told you 8 days ago to use `inlineformset_factory` and not `modelformset_factory` and how to pass `initial` in. You then said there was an error but when you say there is an error, you should always say what the error is and paste a full stack trace. If you do that I can help further. "there is an error" doesn't tell us what's wrong.

Comment: So please update your question with the code you've tried using the `inlineformset_factory` and show us the error. Now you're just duplicating your earlier question.

Comment: my mistake , it is showing initial_hod not defined 'Name error' at ```context['formset'] = AttendanceFormset(queryset=Attendance.objects.none(), instance=initial_hod, initial=[{'employee': employee} for employee inself.get_initial()['employee']])``` i have updated the question

Comment: I used `initial_hod` as an example, you need to use your head of department there. (the `hod` in `get_context_data()`).

Comment: i updated the question ```Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email)``` , now it's showing ```The view attendanceapp.views.Attendancecreate didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.``` and template is not rendering the employees

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194502/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-coder13).

Comment: @dirkgroten it's still raising ```value error : attendanceapp.views.Attendancecreate didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead``` , mentioned in the chat in detail

Comment: Your post method doesn’t do anything if the form set is not valid.

Comment: i can't identify the problem why its invalid or what i am missing in the code

Comment: You need to handle the case the formset is not valid: `else: return form_invalid(formset)` and write a form invalid method. Then you’ll be able to see the errors. Also use a debugger that way you can inspect your formset and check the errors

Comment: @dirkgroten , i tried to print formset.errors and it showed [] as i mentioned in the updated question , please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing request.post ,

```
class Attendancecreate(CreateView):
    ...
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs,):
        formset = AttendanceFormset(request.POST,queryset=Attendance.objects.none(), instance=Head_of_department.objects.get(email=self.request.user.email), initial=[{'employee': employee} for employee in self.get_initial()['employee']])
        if formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(formset)
```

#### Template

```html
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
     {% for form in formset %}
          {{ form.employee.initial }} {{ form.employee}}  {{ form.attendance }}
<br><br>
     {% endfor %}
```